# Issue with removing and adding Array elements

Tags: javascript

I have an array with different food things, and then a prompt where you can choose one of these things at the time, and then i want to show them what they choosed in the "grocery()" function, but it only displays "done" as it was the last word i typed, is there anyway to take out the thing from the first array, when i type it in the prompt, and store it in a new array variable, and the display it after? I've tried everything i can.

Can anyone please help! i would appreciate it! :)

Heres the code

```
function blue() {
    alert("You start walking on the blue road");
    alert("You spot a grocery store at the side of the road.");
    alert("You decide to walk inside, and buy yourself some food.")
    alert("You open the door to the store, you hear a loud bell as you opened the door.")
    alert("You notice the cashier turning her head towards you.")
    alert("You take a bag, and nods politely, then walks in to the store.")
    alert("Heres a list of all the things available in the store.")
    var inStock = ['apples', 'eggs', 'milk', 'cookies', 'cheese', 'bread', 'ham', 'carrot',
        'broccoli', 'pizza', 'crackers', 'onion', 'banana', 'frozen dinner', 'cereals'
    ];
    var search = prompt(inStock + " " + "Choose wich things you wanna buy, type 'done' when you are done." + " type one thing at the time.");

    while (inStock.indexOf(search) > -1) {
        alert("You grabbed a " + search + " and put it in the bag")
        search = prompt(inStock + " " + "Choose wich things you wanna buy, type 'done' when you are done." + " type one thing at the time.")
        if (search === "done") {
            grocery();

        }

    }

    function grocery() {
        alert("You decided that its enough")
        alert("In your bag you have " + search);
    }   

}
```

Comment: can you add a quick jsfiddle?

Comment: I hope you're only using `prompt` and `alert` for learning purposes. You'll need to store the indexes in an Array and `delete` those elements out or reassign `inStock`.

Comment: Well, yeah. Im using prompt and alert for learning purposes, as they are the only thing i know at the moment, to use, when making a text game. And i have not learned how to store indexes or reassign Arrays yet.

Comment: Hint:  The output mentions a bag.  But there is no bag in the code.  Where's the bag?  A bag must be defined and things put in it.  Instead, the grocery() function prints the name of the last item.  This is not a bag.  At best it is a bag with a hole in it.

Comment: And heres the jsfiddle!:) https://jsfiddle.net/nedvLoop/

Answer (score 3):

That's because of this line:

```
alert("In your bag you have " + search);
```

It says "done" because you put the "search" value in your message. You are asking the user to type "done", and thus `search=="done"`.

You need to create something to keep each item entered, like another array:

```
var inBag = [];
```

Each time the user enters an item, add it like so:

```
inBag.push(search);
```

Here is a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/vknvLtzb/1/

Comment: Yeah i know, but i wonder how i can display, everything the user typed in. and not the "done" word.

Comment: That doesn't fix the `grocery()` function.  He needs another array, and `array.push()` or similar.

Comment: Yeah, this fixed it. thanks, one thing tough, why did you use "inStock.indexOf(search) >= 0" instead of "> -1" ?

Comment: Because if something is found, the index will be greater or equal to 0 (>=0), which is greater than -1. Just another way to do the same thing. :P

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you keep reassigning `search` to the new value every time, you're never storing previous values.

There are a couple ways to do this too. My preference would be to create an array and stick all the none-done inputs into that array. Then you can just join them with ", " and get a nice bit of sentence.

Add in this bit:

```
var search = prompt(inStock + " " + "Choose wich things you wanna buy, type 'done' when you are done." + " type one thing at the time.");
var bag = []; //Shorthand for an empty array
bag.push(search); //adding your first selection to the bag array
```

This declares an array, since search is just a string value. This `bag` array can be used to hold all your items. Since the loop you're using is a little iffy, we have to add the first search item to the bag immediately.

Then, change your "if done" to this:

```
if (search === "done") {
    grocery();
}else{
     bag.push(search);   
}
```

This checks for each attempt, if it's not "done" it adds it to the bag. Otherwise it calls your function.

Then change your final bit to:

```
alert("In your bag you have " + bag.join(", "));
```

`join` combines all elements in the array to a string, using the quoted bit as "glue". In this case, it makes a nice sentence.

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sharf224/dbdLdx8n/1/).

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track but the main problem is you are constantly overwriting the `search` value and not storing it on every iteration.

```js
function blue() {
  var search;
  var index;
  var items = [];
  var inStock = [
    'apples',
    'eggs',
    'milk',
    'cookies',
    'cheese',
    'bread',
    'ham',
    'carrot',
    'broccoli',
    'pizza',
    'crackers',
    'onion',
    'banana',
    'frozen dinner',
    'cereals'
  ];

  alert("You start walking on the blue road");
  alert("You spot a grocery store at the side of the road.");
  alert("You decide to walk inside, and buy yourself some food.");
  alert("You open the door to the store, you hear a loud bell as you opened the door.");
  alert("You notice the cashier turning her head towards you.");
  alert("You take a bag, and nods politely, then walks in to the store.");
  alert("Heres a list of all the things available in the store.");

  search = promptMessage(inStock);

  while (search !== 'done') {
    index = inStock.indexOf(search);

    if (index > -1) {
      items.push(inStock.splice(index, 1)[0]);
      alert("You grabbed a " + search + " and put it in the bag");
    } else {
      alert("Sorry, the store is out of " + search);
    }
    search = prompt(inStock);
  }

  grocery(items);
}

function promptMessage(inStock) {
  return prompt(inStock + " Choose wich things you wanna buy, type 'done' when you are done. Type one thing at the time.");
}

function grocery(items) {
  alert("You decided that its enough");
  alert("In your bag you have " + items);
}

blue();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should store your items in a new array and remove items from the inStock array if the item is valid.

Proof of concept (Added missing semi-colons too):

```js
function blue() {
 alert("You start walking on the blue road.");
 alert("You spot a grocery store at the side of the road.");
 alert("You decide to walk inside, and buy yourself some food.");
 alert("You open the door to the store, you hear a loud bell as you opened the door.");
 alert("You notice the cashier turning her head towards you.");
 alert("You take a bag, and nods politely, then walks in to the store.");
 alert("Heres a list of all the things available in the store.");

 var inStock = [ 'apples', 'eggs', 'milk', 'cookies', 'cheese', 'bread', 'ham', 'carrot', 'broccoli', 'pizza', 'crackers', 'onion', 'banana', 'frozen dinner', 'cereals' ];
 var results = [];
 var search;

 while (search !== 'done') {
  search = prompt(inStock.join(', ') + "\n" + "Choose which things you wanna buy, type 'done' when you are done." + "\n" + "Type one thing at the time.");
  
  if (search === "done") {
   grocery();
   break;
  } else if (inStock.indexOf(search) > -1) {
   alert("You grabbed a " + search + " and put it in the bag");
   results.push(search);
   inStock.splice(inStock.indexOf(search), 1);
  } else {
   alert("Invalid item.");
  }
 }

 function grocery() {
  alert("You decided that its enough")
  alert("In your bag you have " + results.join(', '));
 }
}

blue();
```